# Suspicious files in my Windows

Tags: backdoor

While I am doing a quick scan for virus on Norton 360, I noticed a long stop at some files. Their names are very very suspicious. Although I can't recall all of them, one of them, which I clearly remember, is `Backdoor.Rustock.A`. I searched this on the Internet, and the results are... Pretty shocking. It turned out to be a little virus-like stuff. I tried to remove it but, I can't even FIND the file. Why does Norton skips that file instead of treating it like a virus and removes it? What should I do to remove them (the viruses / virus-like stuff), or are they even harmful?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this http://www.ehow.com/how_5136136_remove-backdoor-rustock.html Also keep in mind that malware can be installed some times in Virtual FileSystem-VFS so tracking it down can be even more difficult.

Comment: Sorry, actually, I am asking for ways to remove ALL viruses, not just Backdoor. Sorry if the wordings are not exact.

Comment: If you can't do it manually-search and destroy-format works for most of the cases, even if it's like using a nuke to kill ants, however if viruses have affected BIOS for example solution could be a new computer :P

Comment: BIOS is alright, and I think the search-and-destroy thing will be fine. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You may also have luck in booting into safemode with networking and running your antivirus and malware scans there. MOST viruses/malware I've run across don't function well in safemode. Good luck and hopefully I've caught you prior to scorched earth strategy.

Comment: Well, the point is, the anti virus itself skipped the files. That makes it impossible to detect viruses.

Comment: Pardon my misunderstanding! Object is locked skipped" is usually a "security" measure that the virus will use to make sure it can't be scanned. The AV will note it was skipped to alert the user and continue on.

To elaborate if I being a virus creator would not want my program removed so I'd take every effort to stop that from taking place. Antivirus I'm sure you're aware is like a flu shot, will catch most of what's thrown but not all. If I can elaborate further please let me know.

There's a simliar thread http://superuser.com/questions/646770/issues-with-avg this what your seeing?